# How can I define two routes for the same controller

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, routes

I have a controller named PaymentsController in a Payments area.
it works when I request 'localhost/payments/payments/index' but I want call with 'localhost/payments/pa/index' or just 'localhost/payments'

I need both names.

I try somthing like

```csh
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Execplan.MVC.Areas.Payments
{
public class PaymentsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Payments";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
       context.MapRoute(
           "Payments_default",
           "Payments/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
       );

       context.MapRoute(
          "Payments_pa",
          "Payments/Pa/{action}/{id}"
           , new { controller = "payments", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
} }
```